# Count numbers within range algorithm (C++)

Tags: c++, algorithm, count, range

I want to print the amount of numbers that are within the range of two numbers (those two numbers included).

I have created this simple code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int one = -5;
  int two = 5;
  unsigned int count = 0;

  int min = std::min(one, two);
  int max = std::max(one, two);

  while (min <= max) {
    count++;
    min++;
  }

  std::cout << count << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

In this example I use -5 to 5 and it correctly prints 11.

How can I improve this algorithm so that it works without problem with numbers ranging from for example -1 billion to 1 billion?

Or is the code fine as it stands?

Comment: what's wrong with `count = two - one`? (the runtime complexity of your "algorithm" is through the roof)

Comment: 10 isn't correct: -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ~ 11 numbers. The actual formula should be `max - min + 1`, since you want to include the max/min.

Comment: @Zeta You are right, I corrected my code ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of numbers in that range is simply their difference + 1:

```
count = max - min + 1;
```

Or, without evaluating which is the max and which the min, use the absolute value of the difference

```
count = std::abs(one - two) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I missed something, but

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int one = -5;
    int two = 5;
    unsigned int count = std::abs(one-two)+1;

    std::cout << count << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

should do exactly what you want?

This will give 11 for -5 and 5, which is in fact the count of numbers betweeen -5 and 5, including both. If you want it to print 10, as you said in your quetion you have to remove the `+1`.

Comment: `std::abs(two - one)?`

Answer (score -1):

You need to use an integral type that can contain such range of numbers. At present the greatest fundamental signed integral type in C++ is `long long int` You can get the range of numbers it can store by using expressions

`std::numeric_limits<long long int>::min()` and `std::numeric_limits<long long int>::max()`

structure `std::numeric_limits` is defined in header `<limits>`

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
   std::cout << std::numeric_limits<long long int>::min() << " - "
             << std::numeric_limits<long long int>::max() << std::endl;
}
```

Also it would be better if the program would ask the user to enter the two numbers. For big ranges it is better to use a simple arithmetic expression to get the counter instead of using the loop.

Comment: How would you assert that `long long int` is _long enough_? You're on a track here, but... You say all these things, but explain very little. I'd say, precisely when the numbers are being input it's much more than "it is better to use an expression [...] instead of using the loop" - the loop would be a flat-outout DOS attack vector

Comment: @sehe I showed how to get the acceptable range of numbers for long long int. So whether it si long enough or not you can decide yourself.

Comment: Long enough or not, be careful that it doesn’t get too long for GCC.